# Ввод данных в цикле while

Tags: c++, циклы

Занимаюсь по книжке Страуструпа и одном из заданий нужно реализовать ввод данных с клавиатуры, но у меня возникли проблемы с функций `name_pairs::read_ages`. Функция не дает возможности ввода данных, просто выводит введенные до этого переменные и все.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>



class name_pairs
{
public:

    void name_pairs::read_names();
    void name_pairs::read_ages();
    void name_pairs::print();

private:

    std::vector<std::string>name_vector;
    std::vector<double>age_vector;
};

void name_pairs::read_names()
{
    std::string name;

    while (std::cin>> name)
    {
        name_vector.push_back(name);
    }
}

void name_pairs::read_ages()
{
    int age;

    for (const std::string& name : name_vector )
    {
        std::cout << name << ": ";
        std::cin >> age;
        age_vector.push_back(age);
        std::cout << std::endl;
        
    }
}

void name_pairs::print()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < name_vector.size(); i++ )
    {
        std::cout << name_vector[i] << " - " << age_vector[i] << std::endl;
    }
}






int main()
{
    name_pairs jojo;
    jojo.read_names();
    jojo.read_ages();
    jojo.print();
}
```

Comment: ваш пример не компилируется. исправьте на рабочий.

Comment: А что за странный код `name_pairs() { name_vector; age_vector; }`? Вряд ли у Страуструпа такое ненужное было... Что до вашего кода: а как вы завершаете ввод имен? Он же не имеет ограничителя, и вводятся ad infinitum только имена, до возраста код не доходит, разве что с закрытым `cin`, из которого уже ничего не прочтешь...

Comment: Странно, у меня все компилируется использую clang

Comment: https://ideone.com/pO51f7

Comment: @Harry на это не обращайте внимание. Я просто хотел просто создать дефолтный конструктор, и дальше забил на его реализацию, т.к. есть проблемы более насущные

Comment: @Harry я завершаю ввод данных с помощью control + z

Comment: Это и есть то, что я написал выше — "*разве что с закрытым `cin`, из которого уже ничего не прочтешь...*". Все, `cin` закрыт, читать из него ничего нельзя, все операции `cin>>age` просто игнорируются, вот вы и получаете просто вывод имен...

Comment: А как можно по-другому это реализовать?